# Creating a user using Services results in user not being able authenticate using HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: services, users

I'm developing a backend for an Android application using Drupal, and I've run into somewhat of a weird problem. I'm using Services and Views for the input and output of various content types. In order to make requests to the Services module, the users need to authenticate using HTTP Basic authentication.

When users create a new account in my app, I use the Services endpoint to create the new account using data that the user enters himself. However, the password that gets send to the endpoint is not the same as the password that gets saved. 
This results in users not being able to authenticate other requests using HTTP Basic Auth with the password they set, as Drupal does not recognize the password. However, logging in using the Services endpoint DOES work with the set password.

When changing this user's password manually in the Administration panel to the value they set in the app, the HTTP Basic auth requests suddenly work, and they can still login using the Services module as well.

What's going wrong here, and even better, what can I do to remedy this problem? I'm not looking forward to changing every user's password manually so they can use the rest of my backend, and dropping the HTTP Basic Authentication is not an option either.

Edit:

Further investigation has shown that it's also not possible to login to the Drupal frontend using an account created by the Services endpoint, unless you change the password manually.

Comment: Instead of basic auth, perhaps you could use a token / hash based authentication instead?

Comment: @DavidThomas This was the original idea, but it was dropped by my project leader after running into problems getting it to work on iOS devices. Http Basic auth  worked on both platforms without any hiccups so far, hence the choice for using HTTP Basic auth.

Comment: Probably something overwriting the authorization header preventing the basic auth

Comment: @DavidThomas Sadly no, I just created a new account using the Services endpoint with the username and password "test", and upon trying to login using my normal Drupal frontend it tells me my password is incorrect. Logging into the admin panel and setting the password of this account to "test" manually suddenly makes it possible to log in to the front end as well. Somewhere, something is going wrong and I have no clue what or why.

Comment: This is what I do using CURL in php for basic Auth, may be you get some point from this, I don't know how things works on android.

http://pastebin.com/Arzag9Xy

Comment: @shrish Thanks for your code! By the looks of it I do the exact same. The problem isn't in the HTTP Basic authentication, as it works perfectly fine after setting an account's password manually. It doesn't matter if I use my app or tools like Postman for this, the results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sander van't Veer - I struggled with this same problem recently. It looks like there's a bug in the services module where the password doesn't get set. Try this patch and you should be good.

https://drupal.org/files/issues/user_create-2198005-1.patch

Comment: Eventually I found the same patch you linked to and managed to fix my problem. I commented about it on another question bit totally forgot about my own one! Thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: Sure. Did you also have an issue with setting other fields on the user like "roles" and "notify"? I'm having an issue with that still.

Comment: I had some problems with setting roles but these were quickly fixed. What problems are you running into?

Comment: I created a role in the Drupal admin. When I create the user either using Poster or within my app code (ios/objective c) and set the role, it doesn't seem to take. I also tried setting the "notify" property to 0 because I don't want to send out an email to the user after they register, but the site still sends out the email. Is there some bug in the module for setting "roles" and "notify" properties? The user seems to be created fine otherwise besides these properties not being set correctly.

Comment: I'm currently not at home so I can't provide a code example, but I know we set the role of our user using something like roles:["id_of_the_role"]. With notify i haven't ran into issues, but we turned off notifying our users by default.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried many different formats but they don't seem to take. I'll keep looking into it, but it's good to know there's not a bug in the services module so I can eliminate that. I'm using the latest release version of Services (7.x-3.7). Were you using the latest stable version or were you using a dev/beta version?

Comment: We're using the latest stable version so that would also be 7.x-3.7. How are you currently trying to set your role? Make sure you send the actual id of the role you're trying to set as otherwise it won't be picked up by Drupal and no error is shown to indicate you did anything wrong as you've noticed.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're familiar with objective c, but in my app code I'm creating an array for the role ids (just one id for my custom role) and then setting a dictionary object with my role array for key "roles".

Here's the code:
NSMutableDictionary *userData = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSArray *userRoleData = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"4"];
[userData setValue:userRoleData forKey:@"roles"];

Comment: I just tried posting from the Poster Firefox plugin and I'm getting the same result with the notify and roles not being sent. Here's the json data I'm posting. The user gets create successfully.  {
"roles":[4],
"notify":"0",
"name":"testuser5",
"pass":"password",
"mail":"testuser5@email.com"
}

Comment: Make sure you put quotes around the id

Comment: That also didn't work. I just tried it again to make sure. I also removed any white space in case that was causing an issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hmm odd. I'll have a look at my own code and get back to you later this weekend.  Edit:had some code on dropbox, we create our users like so {

  "name": "....",

  "mail": "....,

  "pass": "...",

  "status": "1",

  "roles": [

    "5"

  ]

}

 Where 5 is the id of the role we wish to give our users

Comment: Thank you so much for posting your code. I used your code exactly with the spacing and field order, but it's still not working :(. My role id is definitely 4. It's weird that "notify" and "status" are not being set as well. I'm not sure if you're able to set the "status" to "0", but if I try, the status is still 1 for that user. Here's the exact code I just used: { "name": "testuser5", "mail": "testuser5@email.com", "pass": "password", "status": "1", "roles": [ "4" ] }

Comment: I finally figured out the issue. The user that was creating the user from my app had to have the "administer user permissions" permissions. I didn't have that checked because I thought it was a security vulnerability but apparently it's required. Thank you so much for your help! Setting the "status" of the user is now resolved as well. Now I just have the issue of setting the "notify". Thanks again!